# global macro 'INVALIDATION_ADDR' of type 'void' not referenced [MISRA 2012 Rule 2.5, advisory]

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

I observed the above warning when I define `MACRO` but not used anywhere in code. But at some instance, I am getting this warning for the `MACRO` which is being used in code as well.

I have defined macro - INVALIDATION_ADDR and used at some places as well. However, I observed the same MISRA warning. I am not sure regarding the reason to get this warning. How to avoid this warning.

Case 1:

> global macro 'INVALIDATION_ADDR' of type 'void' not referenced [MISRA
>   2012 Rule 2.5, advisory]

lint rule 755

> global macro 'Symbol' (Location) not referenced -- A 'global'
>         macro is one defined in a header file.  This message is given for
>         macros defined in non-library headers.  The macro is not used in
>         any of the modules comprising the program.  This message is
>         suppressed for unit checkout (-u option).

```
typedef uint32 AddressType;

#define INVALIDATION_ADDRESS   (AddressType)0x12345678U

void fun1()
{
     AddressType Address;
     Address = INVALIDATION_ADDRESS;
}
```

Case 2:

> global typedef 'ConditionsEnumType' of type
>   'ConditionsEnumType' (line 110, file
>   ITypes.h) not referenced [MISRA 2012 Rule 2.3,
>   advisory]

lint rule 756

> global typedef 'Symbol' (Location) not referenced -- This message
>         is given for a typedef symbol declared in a non-library header
>         file.  The symbol is not used in any of the modules comprising a
>         program.  This message is suppressed for unit checkout (-u
>         option).

```
typedef unsigned char       uint8; 
typedef uint8 StateType;

typedef enum
    {
        BLOCK      =  0x80U,
        HEADER     =  0x81U,
        DATA       =  0x82U,    
        OUTCOME    =  0x84U
    } ConditionsEnumType;

/* used in below func */ 
    void fun2()
    {
         StateType state;
         state = (StateType) BLOCK; 
    }
```

Comment: Would you mind to show us the **real** source (of a [example]) not the one made up for this question, please? Evidences: In case 1 the diagnostic talks about `INVALIDATION_ADDR` but your source uses `INVALIDATION_ADDRESS`. This might be the error, though. The source of case 2 can't be compiled due to the spelling error `unsinged`. Anyway, in case 2 you declare the variable `state` as `unsigned char` and not as `ConditionsEnumType` so the MISRA checker is right.

Comment: Now I checked, all MACRO belongs to the same source (.h) file. Checking if that file is included in compilation or not.

Comment: @thebusybee corrected the spelling error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Case 1:**

This diagnostic:

> ```
> global macro 'INVALIDATION_ADDR' of type 'void' not referenced [MISRA 2012 Rule 2.5, advisory]
> ```

does not match this macro:

> ```
> #define INVALIDATION_ADDRESS   (AddressType)0x12345678U
> ```

So I think the MISRA checker is right because you have another macro definition that is not referenced.

**Case 2:**

The typedef of `ConditionsEnumType` is in fact not referenced if you don't define any variable with this type.

You might like to change your source into:

```
void fun2()
{
     ConditionsEnumType state;
     state = BLOCK; 
}
```